# What is Hypergeometric2F1^(0,0,1,0)[a,b,c,e^(4t)]?

Tags: functions

Please would somebody tell me how to calculate the numerical value of this 
function for example if `a=1, b=5/4, c=9/4 and t=1`?

```
Hypergeometric2F1^(0,0,1,0)[a,b,c,e^(4t)]
```

Mathematica (6.0.2.0) returns back the input with no numerical value.

Do I have to load a specific package to deal with it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your `e` needs to be `E`, assuming it refers to the mathematical constant $e$.

Answer (score 2):

```
D[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, E^(4 t)], c] /.
  {a -> 1, b -> 5/4, c -> 9/4, t -> 1} // N
(*    -0.0406301 - 0.0299334 I    *)
```

Without the trailing `// N` the result looks like nothing was done, as usual in *Mathematica* where exact results are propagated until the user explicitly requests a conversion to numerical.

Comment: What could be the reason why `Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1, 5/4, 9/4, e^(4 1)] // N` doesn't evaluate? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Works fine if you use `E` instead of `e`.

Comment: @ AccidentalFourierTransform How simple , you saved my day.Thank you!